# NameError: global name 'result' is no defined

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to split my code into 2 python files to make it more tidy. But then, I had an NameError.

Here is my simplified code:

report.py

```
def report():
 print result
```

master.py

```
from report import *
global result
result = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
report()
```

When I run the master.py, I get the NameError: global name 'result' is not defined.
I have defined it as global, but have no idea why it's still return error.

Comment: `global` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Here are a couple links that explain how to use `global` in Python.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python  
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/global-statement.html

Comment: I would pass `result` as an argument to `report()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That completely won't work. `result` only exists in the module it's defined in; other modules will not have explicit access to it even if you use `global` properly.